# Simple Instructions Python Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance

A program has one register, X, initialized to 0, and supports only 3 instructions:

LDI v: Load (store) the immediate value, v, into X
ADD v: Add the immediate value v to X and store the result in X.
SQR: Square the value of X and store the result in X.

An example of how the value of  would be affected by a short sequence of instructions:

```
Instruction     X
LDI 5           5
ADD 2           7
SQR             49
ADD -4          44
LDI -3          -3
SQR             9
```

The problem I need to solve is to skip selected instructions to get the largest possible value for `X` at program end.

What I have so far:

```
def prog(n):
    x = 0
    arr = []
    for i in range(n):
        itm = input().split()
        arr += [(itm)]
    #arr_rev = arr[::-1]    
    #limit = arr_rev.index(["SQR"])+len(arr)-1
    limit = len(arr) - 1 - arr[::-1].index(['SQR'])

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if i < limit:
            if arr[i][0] == "ADD":
                x += int(arr[i][1])
            elif arr[i][0] == "LDI":
                x = int(arr[i][1])
            elif arr[i][0] == "SQR":
                x = x**2
        else:
            if arr[i][0] == "ADD" and int(arr[i][1]) > 0:
                x += int(arr[i][1])
            elif arr[i][0] == "LDI" and int(arr[i][1]) > x:
                x = int(arr[i][1])
            elif arr[i][0] == "SQR":
                x = x**2

    return x
```

Since I don't want to add negative numbers, I skip those. I also don't want to load a number less than the current `X`.

However, *squaring* a negative number makes it positive, so the above strategy may not work in all cases. I exempted that rule in all cases until I pass the last SQR. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: There's a nice [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) algorithm for this.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand this @internet_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "more efficient", you mean "might be correct", then **yes**.  Your current code doesn't work for all inputs.  With that SQR "wild-card", you cannot trivially know whether the operation you're looking at is beneficial.  For instance

```
LDI  1
ADD -8
LDI  2
ADD -1
ADD  3
SQR
```

The maximum value comes from (-8 + -1)^2.  You should use dynamic programming (see the link provided in the first comment) to keep track of all "best possible" results at each step.

You classically program this with a recursive routine that tries two branches as it considers each instruction: use / don't use that instruction in the final answer.  Then you recur with the current value of `X` and the remaining instruction list.

---

If you *want* to do data-flow analysis, you *can* apply various short-cuts.  For instance, in any stream of `ADD` instructions, you can combine all negative and all positive values into a single `ADD`.  When you have a `LDI`, you consider whether the new value is greater in both true and absolute value -- the latter being what drives an improvement through `SQR`.

Frankly, I recommend doing the bisect-recur-dynamic_programming route.

---

**UPDATE**

I gave this more thought.  Although DP is the way to go for large problems, this is *not* what you'll want to attack first (in my opinion).  Rather, attack the problem of whether or not to include each particular command.  You will need to do both, until further refinement.  You can't even guarantee that you want to include the `SQR` command: a subsequent subtraction can make it undesirable.

The logic of the recursion is something like this:

```
def optimize(x_reg, command_list):
    # x_reg          current value of the X register
    # command_list   remaining list of commands

    # base case
    if len(command_list) == 0
         return x_reg

    # recursion case
    op = command_list[0][0]
    if op == "ADD":
        new_x = x_reg + command_list[0][1]
    elif op == "LDI":
        new_x = command_list[0][1]
    else:    # op == "SQR":
        new_x = x_reg * x_reg

    with_op = optimize(new_x, command_list[1:])  # Use the command
    sans_op = optimize(x_reg, command_list[1:])  # Don't use the command

    return max(with_op, sans_op)    # Return the larger of the two solutions found
```

Comment: I had some trouble understanding how exactly I could use DP to solve, but I did some reading on DP and it seems quite powerful and is an interesting approach.

Comment: In this case, you would keep track of the answers you get for each combination of input values -- that's called "memoizing".  Then, if a branch of recursion gets you to a combination you've already computed, you find that in your memo table and return the stored value instead of repeating the computation.

Comment: Thank you @Prune , your implementation works and I learned a lot. This takes a lot of time to run though. If I find another approach that runs faster, I will share with you. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, it's slow.  Given the variety of paths you have, it will get *much* worse as your programs get longer.  It shouldn't be too slow with only 6 statements, as you have only 2^6 paths to try.  You can speed up the longer cases somewhat with DP, but the problem itself isn't trivial.